# Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $messageFactory

Tags: magento2, email, newsletter, magento2.4

I have upgraded Magento version 2.3.5-p1 to Magento 2.4.0 after the upgrade it's showing me an error regarding newsletter files below are the error. I am running below command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

**Error Message**

```
Compilation was started.
Interception cache generation... 6/8 [=====================>------]  75% 52 secs 572.0 MiBErrors during compilation:
        Magento\Newsletter\Model\Queue\TransportBuilder
                Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $messageFactory, $emailMessageInterfaceFactory, $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory, $mimePartInterfaceFactory, $addressConverter. File: /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Queue/TransportBuilder.php
Total Errors Count: 1

In Log.php line 92:
                            
  Error during compilation
```

**Transport Builder code**

```
public function __construct(
    FactoryInterface $templateFactory,
    MessageInterface $message,
    SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver,
    ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    TransportInterfaceFactory $mailTransportFactory,
    MessageInterfaceFactory $messageFactory = null,
    EmailMessageInterfaceFactory $emailMessageInterfaceFactory = null,
    MimeMessageInterfaceFactory $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory = null,
    MimePartInterfaceFactory $mimePartInterfaceFactory = null,
    AddressConverter $addressConverter = null
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $templateFactory,
        $message,
        $senderResolver,
        $objectManager,
        $mailTransportFactory,
        $messageFactory,
        $emailMessageInterfaceFactory,
        $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory,
        $mimePartInterfaceFactory,
        $addressConverter
    );
    $this->emailMessageInterfaceFactory = $emailMessageInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
        ->get(EmailMessageInterfaceFactory::class);
    $this->mimeMessageInterfaceFactory = $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
        ->get(MimeMessageInterfaceFactory::class);
    $this->mimePartInterfaceFactory = $mimePartInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
        ->get(MimePartInterfaceFactory::class);
    $this->addressConverter = $addressConverter ?: $this->objectManager
        ->get(AddressConverter::class);
}
```

**It's extending below file**
**Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder**

```
public function __construct(
    FactoryInterface $templateFactory,
    MessageInterface $message,
    SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver,
    ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    TransportInterfaceFactory $mailTransportFactory,
    MessageInterfaceFactory $messageFactory = null,
    EmailMessageInterfaceFactory $emailMessageInterfaceFactory = null,
    MimeMessageInterfaceFactory $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory = null,
    MimePartInterfaceFactory $mimePartInterfaceFactory = null,
    AddressConverter $addressConverter = null
) {
    $this->templateFactory = $templateFactory;
    $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_senderResolver = $senderResolver;
    $this->mailTransportFactory = $mailTransportFactory;
    $this->emailMessageInterfaceFactory = $emailMessageInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
        ->get(EmailMessageInterfaceFactory::class);
    $this->mimeMessageInterfaceFactory = $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
        ->get(MimeMessageInterfaceFactory::class);
    $this->mimePartInterfaceFactory = $mimePartInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
        ->get(MimePartInterfaceFactory::class);
    $this->addressConverter = $addressConverter ?: $this->objectManager
        ->get(AddressConverter::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the Composer packages completely.

```
composer clear-cache
rm -rf vendor/* generated/* composer.lock
composer update -vvv
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: it's showing this error,

Magento\Newsletter\Model\Queue\TransportBuilder::setFrom($from) should be compatible with Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBui  
  lder::setFrom($from, $store = NULL) in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Queue/TransportBuilder.php on line 191

Comment: I passed this store in core file(temp basis) but after this same error which I reported in question is coming.

Comment: When I update newsletter Transport builder file with these params then it's working.

parent::__construct(
           $templateFactory,
            $message,
            $senderResolver,
            $objectManager,
            $mailTransportFactory
        );

but why it's not coming in the default file.

Comment: It must be coming as you did by default.

Comment: Issue solved by adding required parameters in construct in core file